# Analysis Question? Fixed Point?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How would you go about proving this assertion?

> $f:A \to A$ has a fixed point iff the graph of f intersects the diagonal

Also, in class we've proven that given $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$ and letting $f:[a,b] \to [a,b]$ be continuous, $f$ has a fixed point, that is, there is an $x \in [a,b]$ with $f(x)=x$.

But does this hold for $f:(a,b) \to (a,b)$ and discontinuous functions?

Comment: It is practically the definition of fixed point!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that was proven in class is different from what you are trying to prove.  By the diagonal, I assume you mean the line $y=x$.  Remember, that when you are graphing a function, you are graphing the equation $y=f(x)$.  So, if $f(x)=x$, then $y=x$.  In other words the point $(x,x)$ is on the graph of $f(x)$ and on the line $y=x$.

Comment: Thanks Tim! I think I have a better understanding now.

Comment: And yes, I knew those two points were not necessarily related... they were just separate uncertainties I had about the material :)

Comment: Glad I could help.