# Function Transformations - how do I find the invariant points?

Tags: functions

When they give you a picture of a graph (doesn't matter what kind - linear, parabola, inverse, etc.) how do you find the invariant points?

Comment: Possibly related: [Analysis Question? Fixed Point?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1153979) and [Fixed point location for functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1180944)

Comment: I believe the question is how to determine invariant points between a function and it's inverse. If you're looking to algebraically find the point, you just make the two functions equal each other, and then solve for x.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for points where $f(x)=x$. Phrased differently, you're looking for points where $(x,x)$ lies on your graph. Rephrased once more, you're looking for intersection with the line $y=x$.

Comment: I get what I am looking for but how do I find it?

Comment: Draw the line $y=x$, and look for intersection with the given graph.

Comment: Is there any way to do it algebraically?

Comment: Wait, are you given a picture or equation? If you have the equation, set $f(x)=x$ and try to solve for $x$. I can't be more specific without more details about what $f$ looks like. Sometimes it's possible, sometimes it's not.

Comment: It is just a picture of a graph of two porabolas side by side (one is a reflection over the y-intercept) that will eventually intersect but do not in the picture.

Comment: If you don't have any equations, then you can't do any algebra.